# Find the smallest eigenvalue of $G=[ \exp(-(x_i-x_j )^2]_{i,j}$ for ${\bf x}=[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Consider a sequence $\{x_1,...,x_n \}$ such that $b=\max_i  |x_i|$ and $d_{\min}=\min_{ij: i \neq j} |x_i-x_j|$.  We assume that $b<\infty$ and $d_{\min}>0$.

Can we find a non-trivial lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of
$$G=[ \exp(-(x_i-x_j )^2)]_{i=1..n,j=1..n}$$

We want this lower bound to depend on some property of this sequence.

I was thinking of writing it as
\begin{align}
u^T G u =\sum_i \sum_j  u_i u_j   \exp(-(x_i-x_j )^2)
\end{align}
and showing a lower bound that holds for all $(u_i,u_j)$.

We have the following bounds on each entry
$$\exp(-d_{\min}^2) \ge \exp(-(x_i-x_j )^2) \ge  \exp(-4 b^2).$$  However, I don't know how to combine these two steps.

Note that we know that $G$ is positive definite. This follows since $\exp(-t^2)$ is [a positive definite kernel.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel)

Comment: If you know that $G$ is positive definite, then all of its eigenvalues are greater than $0$.  If $\lambda_{1}$ is the smallest eigenvalue, you can let $m=\lambda_{1}/2$ and be done.  Is there something more to this question?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Sure. But can we find this smallest eigenvalue or lower bond on it? Ideally, we would like it to depend only on some properties of the sequence. For example, $b$.

Comment: Are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ distinct? If not, we will have two identical rows/columns, and $0$ will be an eigenvalue.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 good point. I will add this.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone think about this problem further, $\begin{bmatrix}1&e^{-d_{\text{min}}^2}\\e^{-d_{\text{min}}^2}&1\end{bmatrix}$ is a proper submatrix of $G$, so the smallest eigenvalue is at most $1-e^{-d_{\text{min}}^2}$, but could be smaller.

Comment: Your bound would have to depend on both $b$ and $d_{\min}$, Try $x_{1}=1 \times 10^{6}$, $x_{2}=1 \times 10^{-6}$, $x_{3}=2 \times 10^{-6}$ for example.

Comment: @JimmyK4542  Thank you!!!

Comment: @BrianBorchers  I guess it makes sense. It's both important how spread and how dense this sequence is.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes... Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook example for applying the [Gerschgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem): The eigenvalues are located somewhere in the union of discs $D_{r_i}(G_{ii})$ of radius $r_i = \sum_{j\neq i} |G_{ij}|$. Here, we have $G_{ii}=1$ for all $i$ and we can bound the radii as:

$$ 
r_i = \sum_{j\neq i} |G_{ij}| = \sum_{j\neq i} e^{-(x_i-x_j)^2} \le \sum_{j\neq i} e^{-d_\min^2} = (n-1) e^{-d_\min^2}
$$

Thus you have the lower bound $\lambda_\min(G) \ge 1 - (n-1) e^{-d_\min^2}$. Of course this bound is only useful if $d_\min$ is sufficiently large, i.e. if $d_\min > \sqrt{\log(n-1)}$

In the case when the $x$-values are known you can of course improve the bound towards

$$ \lambda_\min(G) \ge 1 - r_\max \qquad r_\max=\max_i \sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n e^{-{(x_i-x_j)^2}} $$

Comment: Quick question.  There are $n^2-n$ terms it that sum and not $(n-1)$, right?

Comment: @Lisa there are only $n-1$ terms: the $i$-th radius is given by the sum of the absolute values over the $i$-th row, except the diagonal entry. Since all the diagonal entries are the same, we only need to consider the largest radii; but our upper bound is the same for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Put $D=\exp(-d_{\min}^2)<1$. Let $\lambda_{\min}$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $G$. It turns out, that the [simple bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765845/find-the-smalles-eigenvalue-of-g-exp-x-i-x-j-2-i-j-for-bf-x-x-1#comment7748191_3765845) $\lambda_{\min}\le 1-D$ by JimmyK4542 is rather tight, especially for small $n$ and big $d_{\min}$.  Namely, we have $\lambda_{\min}\ge 1-E,$ where $$E=D+D+D^4+D^4+D^9+D^9+\dots$$
(the right-hand-side has $n-1$ summands).

Let’s prove this. Let $x’_1,\dots, x’_n$ be a permutation of the numbers $x_i$ such that $x’_1<x’_2<\dots<x’_n$. Then for each $i,j$ we have $|x’_i-x’_j|\le |i-j|d_{min}$, and so $$\exp(-(x’_i-x’_j)^2)\le \exp(-(i-j)^2 d_{\min}^2)=D^{(i-j)^2}.$$
This easily follows that for each $i$ $$S_i=\sum_{j\ne i} \exp(-(x_i-x_j)^2)\le E.$$
Thus if $\lambda<1-E$ then $G-\lambda I$ is a [strictly diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), so it is non-singular by [Levy–Desplanques theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties), that is $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of  $G$.

Moreover, for $n=3$, $\lambda_{\min}\ge 1-D\sqrt{2+D^6}$. Indeed, let $G=\|g_{ij}\|$. Then

$$|G-\lambda I|=(1-\lambda)^3+2g_{12}g_{13}g_{23}-(1-\lambda)(g_{12}^2+g_{13}^2+g_{23}^2).$$

Thus if $\lambda<1$ and  $|G-\lambda I|=0$ then
$$(1-\lambda)^2\le g_{12}^2+g_{13}^2+g_{23}^2\le 2D^2+D^8,$$
so $\lambda\ge 1-D\sqrt{2+D^6}$.